# java 8.31 AccessControlException

Tags: java, security, localhost

I have a set of java web applications I want to run from my own computer, using the TomCat web server. They all worked OK up until I installed java 1.8.0_31.

It took a while to get around the permissions problem to start the application but after that I can't get past an AccessControlException trying to connect to my local "database server" (which runs in TomCat) from my browser.

The database server is running OK, because I can connect to it using the AppletViewer.

I created a policy entry and added it to the runtime java security:
    grant codeBase "http://localhost" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
    };

I've tried some variations on the http://localhost (adding the port and application name) but none of them work. The code base is unchanged since it worked before. With these new security features, I can't run web applications running on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known problem, see:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066655

Unfortunately, it's not scheduled to be fixed until 8u60 and who knows when that will be. Also, attempting to back out 8.31 has its own set of problems: Once I uninstalled 8.31 and attempted to install any other earlier JRE, neither Firefox nor IE would recognize that earlier JRE. I just got a "missing plugin" message, and the Java plugin was not present in either browser's plugin list.

Comment: The problem with the unrecognized plug-in was due to installing the 64 bit version, and I have 32-bit browsers installed.